# Backup SQL Server Maintenance Plan

Tags: sql-server-2008, maintenance-plan

Is it possible to backup Maintenance Plan? Is it enough to backup `msdb` database that has all Agent Jobs?  I use SQL Server 2008.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, msdb contains the maint plans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer for this one - yes, keep your MSDB backed up as well as your other databases. (It contains details for other features as well, such as replication, backup history etc)

Edit : will add - back up your master as well whilst you are at it, if you are not doing that already.

Answer (score 1):

You can both import and export maintenance plans. Connect to the Integration Services on the SQL Server instance that hosts the maintenance plans. Use the Stored Packages -> MSDB -> 
Maintenance Plans. Use the context menu of the Maintenance Plans and select the Import option

Or if you open the context menu of one of your maintenance plans, you can select either Import or or Export